# Help installing amdgpu-pro with r9 390

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, tar, extract

Following the directions found on AMD's site here [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx), I run in to a problem trying to extract the drivers. Here is what my terminal reads

~/Downloads$ tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro-16.40-348864.tar.xz

xz: (stdin): File format not recognized

tar: Child returned status 1

tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

I have attempted redownloading the file multiple times, with the same results. Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: [edit] in the output of `file amdgpu-pro-16.40-348864.tar.xz`

Comment: Have you tried installing through the Additional drivers app?