# How to install AMD Drivers for Radeon RX 460?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, tar, archive

I am trying to install my Graphics Driver for my Radeon RX 460 and I am stuck at extracting the content of the `amdgpu-pro-16.40-348864.tar.xz` file. I run `​tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro_16.30.3-348864.tar.xz` from the terminal (I used cd command to navigate to the file) and I get

> termozour@termozour-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ​tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro-16.40-348864.tar.xz
>
> xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
>
> tar: Child returned status 1
>
> tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

I have checked if xz tools is installed, and it is, and updated to the latest version. How can i extract it so I can install it ?

EDIT1: I tried downloading the file again several times, and I still got the same problem.
I emailed AMD regarding the issue, and they have forwarded my email to a more specialized staff, to fix my issue.

I can boot Ubuntu if my GPU is either unplugged from the MoBo or if it's disabled in UEFI BIOS.

Comment: should I send an Email to AMD about the issue ?

Comment: I have tried that several times. It will still not extract

Comment: `termozour@termozour-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ xz -d amdgpu-pro-16.40-348864.tar.xz `.  `xz: amdgpu-pro-16.40-348864.tar.xz: File format not recognized`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I uncompress a tarball that uses .xz?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92328/how-do-i-uncompress-a-tarball-that-uses-xz)

Comment: I have also tried the command posted there. Same result `termozour@termozour-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ tar xf amdgpu-pro-16.40-348864.tar.xz 
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
`

Comment: I have sent an Email to AMD regarding the issue with the possibly corrupt .tar.xz file. I am waiting for a response.

Comment: Interesting. what's the output of `file amdgpu-pro-16.40-348864.tar.xz`

Comment: This post describes the same problem. http://askubuntu.com/questions/851709/help-installing-amdgpu-pro-with-r9-390

Comment: Have you tried installing through the Additional drivers app?

Comment: I have tried that. It will not recognize my GPU(probably because it's disabled from the UEFI BIOS), although if I type `lspci grep | VGA` I can see `Advanced Micro Devices`. No `Radeon RX... `

Answer (score 1):

The archive file is corrupted (probably during an interrupted download). These things happen. Download it anew and try again. If the same problem persists please edit your question to clarify that.

Update: If the file stays corrupted even after a re-download the problem may lie on AMD's side, i. e. they published a broken archive file. This is purported by the fact that you're not [the only one](https://community.amd.com/thread/205615) with this issue.

Comment: I have edited the question regarding the file download. Thank you for suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a GUI just find the file with File Manager and double-click it.
The archive manager should open it for you, and then you can extract.

Comment: If I open the archive with Nautilus, it displays an error trying to open the archive, and an empty window which is actually the archive